# What is a quaternary mirror and why does the E-ELT need one?

Tags: telescope, observatory, e-elt

In this recent [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-36381581) I read the one-sentence paragraph:

> "Development on the mirrors - in particular, a very complex quaternary mirror - continues apace."

and became interested in the following questions:

1. *What is* a quaternary mirror
2. Why does the E-ELT need one
3. What is it about this mirror that is "very complex"?

*note:* the E-ELT is the European Extremely Large Telescope nearing final design, and to be installed in Chile's Atacama Desert (host to many other telescopes).

A drawing of the E-ELT from from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Extremely_Large_Telescope) (note scale of humans):

[image: E-ELT]

An image from the BBC article:

[image: BBC image of E-ELT vs Big Ben]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may know that a standard Newtonian telescope has two mirrors, they are called the primary and secondary mirror.

The E-ELT has five mirrors: The quaternary mirror is simply "mirror number four", counting in the direction the light enters the scope.

It's complex because that's where the adaptive optics sits:

> The quaternary mirror has an approximate diameter of 2.4-m (2380x2340mm). It is a flat adaptive mirror, with up to 8000 actuators, thereby allowing the surface to be readjusted at very high time frequencies. [...]
>
> This mirror will correct in real time for high order wavefront errors (e.g. atmosphere, wind shake, low spatial frequency telescope errors) and small amplitude residual tip-tilt corrections.

Source: The European Southern Observatory's [page on the E-ELT optics](http://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/eelt/telescope/mirrors/)

Comment: OK - exactly what I wanted to know, thank you! I'd say that certainly qualifies as "very complex"!

Comment: another [related question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/15006/7982)

Comment: @uhoh I don't think I can add much to [this answer](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/why-actually-arent-ground-based-observatories-using-adaptive-optics-for-visib) and the ESO page on the [challenges with adaptive optics](http://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/develop/ao/what_ao.html). Looks like "no" to me. Also, there seems to be too few actuators to correct the visual band for a 40 m primary. But that's just my semi-educated guess.

Comment: Thanks! - if that's a comment on the related question, do you think you could *also add it there* so people can see it when they read that question? The idea is to maximize the usefulness of information for future readers.