# How did VLT's adaptive optics obtain this resolution for Neptune? Is it really working in visible wavelengths?

Tags: observational-astronomy, neptune, angular-resolution, adaptive-optics, very-large-telescope

This image of Neptune taken with the VLT is really impressive. The resolution is achieved by recent improvements in the adaptive optics.

- Gizmodo: [New Super-Crisp Images of Neptune Show How Far Our Telescopes Have Come](https://gizmodo.com/new-super-crisp-images-of-neptune-show-how-far-our-tele-1827683475)
- Space.com [Telescope Upgrade Produces Stunningly Clear Views of Space](https://www.space.com/41202-new-adaptive-optics-produces-stunning-views.html)

But I don't really understand, is this coming from just one 8 meter mirror, or is this using more than one of the four that make up the VLT? Also, is this really using adaptive optics *that work in the visible, including blue wavelengths?* Or is this a false-color image? See the excellent answer(s) to [Why (actually) aren't ground-based observatories using adaptive optics for visible wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14795/7982)

[image: Neptune VLT new adaptive optics]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an image taken with the new narrow field mode of the MUSE instrument using the GALACSI Adaptive optics module on a single (UT4) VLT telescope using laser guide stars.

I am having a great deal of difficulty (e.g. from [this press release](http://www.eso.org/public/news/eso1824/)) in working out at what wavelength(s) this image was taken. I do not believe that the AO system is working at blue wavelengths and therefore the comparison with HST (which certainly does) is somewhat misleading. I think ([from ESO's own instrumentation pages](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/paranal/instruments/muse/inst.html)) that the MUSE narrow field mode has zero efficiency at blue wavelengths and the description of [GALACSI](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/develop/ao/sys/galacsi.html) only talks about AO correction approaching diffraction limited images at 650 nm (i.e. red wavelengths).

The captioning to the press release images found [here](http://www.eso.org/public/images/eso1824a/) suggest that the shortest wavelengths used in this **false-colour image** were 550nm and that most of the detail you see is coming from redder wavelengths (600-920nm).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and writing a well-sourced answer! There is a lot of really good material to read here. As far as the collor, the situation reminds me a bit of what happened with [Is the “Mars blue dune” actually blue? And what makes it so?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28082/12102)

Comment: Indeed, MUSE has zero efficiency (in any of its modes) blueward of about 480nm; it's one of the few deficiencies of an otherwise amazing instrument.

Comment: fyi I've just quoted some of this in [What capabilities of Hubble are unique and irreplaceable? What can it do that simply can't be done by any other ground or space-based telescope?]()https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44503/7982)

Comment: Generally "true color" is *hard*. Computer monitors are very limited in terms of producing pure colors and are different from each-other. Eyes are also varied (see: https://www.exploratorium.edu/video/paul-doherty-disagreeing-about-color). Not to mention the small percentage who are tetra-chromatic.

For accurate true color, one may need to measure 12 channels in the visible and reproduce those wavelengths in a special laser projector.